# Set number of options shown in JComboBox when used as JTable RowFilter

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, rowfilter

I'm trying to set the number of options shown in the JComboBox drop down list when it is used as a JTable RowFilter.  Specifically, the filter on occasion can have many options and I'd like to show twice as many as the default (which appears to be 8).  See this image:

[Combox Box Example http://aalto.tv/test/combobox-image.png](http://aalto.tv/test/combobox-image.png)

As you can hopefully see, this ComboBox only shows 8 items and I would like to show more if there are more to be seen.

Having searched around the popular solution is to call "setMaximumRowCount" on the JComboBox, however this is having no effect.

Can any one point me in the right direction?

Many thanks for any and all help!
Cheers,

Alex

Comment: try the revalidate() (or repaint()) method after setting the rowcount;

Answer (score 1):

[JComboBox#setMaximumRowCount](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setMaximumRowCount%28int%29) works for [JTable / TableHeader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox) and [AutoComplete JComboBox](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/AutocompleteComboBox.htm) in the [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) too

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try the revalidate() (or repaint()) method after setting the rowcount;

if a setXX method does not generate an event to the component, then you have to manually reset it.

failing that, look at the source code of the setMaximumRowCount() method